# Bittrex Api in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous

I am trying to read out the public API of Bittrex in pure Javascript. But I can't get it to work. If I call the `coinmakretcap` api instead, it does work. I want to read it asynchronous without using any package. Does anybody have some suggestions on how to achieve this?

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var api = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-UBQ"  ;      
//var api = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/dash/?convert=EUR";

function apicall(api) {

            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", api, true);
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    //obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    obj = xhr.responseText;
                    printanswer(obj);
                }
            };
            xhr.send();
}

function printanswer(obj) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += obj;
}

apicall(api);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not possible as api end point has not enabled access controls for cross side scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bittrex Api is not CORS allowed, because of this you can't run your javascript codes inside your browser. You need to find an Api that supports CORS, or use server-side programs.